# Komascript section header over two column text layout

Tags: koma-script

Is it possible to make \section headers break the two column flow? Two column layout is simply defined in the document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{scrbook}
```

In my document simply works the encapsulation like this:

```
\twocolumn[\section{My section header}]
```

But I want to do through the KOMAscript definition style like:

```
\addtokomafont{section}{\newpage\color{white}}
```

or according to scrguien.pdf 2021-11-09 page 499

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \@tempswafalse
      \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \color{white}
        \newpage
        \hspace*{#2}%
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep-#2}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
      }%
  }
\makeatother
```

Modifiynig `\linewidth` to `\textwidth` doesn't work well. But it's probably the right way to go.

My MNWE example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}    

%------Section-------------------------------------------
% \addtokomafont{section}{\newpage\color{white}}
% scrguien.pdf 2021-11-09 page 499
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \@tempswafalse
      \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \color{white}
        \newpage
        \hspace*{#2}%
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep-#2}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
      }%
  }
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
\chapter{My first junk chapter over two column}
\section{I want to put there long header}
\lipsum[1-4]
\twocolumn[\section{I want to put there long header - twocolumn}]
\lipsum[1-4]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use `\newpage` in the argument of `\addtokomafont`, because it is not a font switch. Also note, with an up-to-date KOMA-Script the English user manual is no longer `scrguien.pdf`, but [`scrguide-en.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `\twocolumn` into `\sectionlineformats`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}    

%------Section-------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
      \twocolumn[%
        \color{white}
        \hspace*{#2}%
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep-#2}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#3}{#4}%
          }%
        }%
      ]%
    }{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
\chapter{My first junk chapter over two column}
\section{I want to put there long header}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{I want to put there long header - twocolumn}
\lipsum[1-4]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But because `\twocolumn` *always* starts a new page, it would also start a new page between `\chapter{…}` and an immediately following `\section{…}`. If this doesn't matter, you could also change the style of `\section` to `chapter`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}    

\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{section}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \color{white}
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
          }%
        }%
      ]%
    }{%
      \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
\chapter{My first junk chapter over two column}
\section{I want to put there long header}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{I want to put there long header - twocolumn}
\lipsum[1-4]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you don't want the page break between `\chapter` and `\section`, you could try a trick:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}    

\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{section}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \color{white}
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
          }%
        }%
      ]%
    }{%
      \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother   

\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble{\section{I want to put there long header}}
\chapter{My first junk chapter over two column}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{I want to put there long header - twocolumn}
\lipsum[1-4]
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you never want to start a new page with `\section`, you need to use a package like [`multicol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I try to put your code into my library and I see unintended effect. I use in documentclass the switch chapterprefix=on. And the effect is that also the section numbering is placed at first line and heading in next line. Do you know how this behaviour can be avoided only for section formatting? Code: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn, chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

Comment: @JardaFait You can use the do-hook `heading/begingroup/section` to locally switch of `chapterprefix`, e.g. using `\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=false}\@gobble}` (after `\makeatletter`). Please see the KOMA-Script manual for more information about the do-hooks.

Comment: Is the \@gobble necessary? There is no argument which should be throw away. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @JardaFait You are wrong. There is an argument. See the documentation of `\AddtoDoHook` in the KOMA-Script manual. You will find an example, that explains this and also recommends to not ignore the argument, even if it would be empty.