# Komascript section redeclare with definition of the page header

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

In my MNWE I try to change style for section in two column [scrbook](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) document. In same time I want to have page header also on pages where the first text line is the section header.

In my code I am loosing the setting of the page header because the section behaves in same manner like chapter. If the page contains only paragraphs it works as I want.

I try to use `\AddtoDoHook` technique but without success (therefore it is commented in MNWE).

**MNWE:**

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662860/komascript-section-header-over-two-column-text-layout
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn, chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[headsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}   
\usepackage{currfile}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}  
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\chead{\currfilename}                              
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114570/koma-script-scrpage2-footer-height 
\ihead{\pagemark}                         % scrguien page 255
\ofoot[]{}                                % remove pagenumber from outer foot
\cfoot[]{}                                % remove pagenumber from centre foot

% \AddtoDoHook appends persistent code to the hook named name.
% \@gobble: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85796/why-does-gobble-take-one-argument
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{section}
\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=false}\@gobble}
% \AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\pagestyle{scrheadings}\@gobble}
% \AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\ihead{\pagemark}  \@gobble}
  % \chapterlinesformat{level}{number}{text}
  \renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    % \Ifstr{string 1}{string 2}{then code}{else code}  page 346 scrguide-en 3.38
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \color{white}
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
          }%
        }%
      ]%
    }{%
      \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother
```

Comment: Use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,pagestyle=scrheadings]{section}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `style=chapter` or `style=part` is used in the optional argument of `\RedeclareSectionCommand` the key `pagestyle` and macro `\<name>pagestyle` are provided.
The key `pagestyle` sets the page style for pages with the heading. By default, the value of key `pagestyle` is `plain`. The macro `\<name>pagestyle` is used to store the value of key `pagestyle`.

So you can use either

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,pagestyle=scrheadings]{section}
```

or

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{section}
\renewcommand*{\sectionpagestyle}{scrheadings}
```

to get the desired result.

First example:

```latex
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662860/komascript-section-header-over-two-column-text-layout
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn, chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[headsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- sets page style scrheadings automatically
\usepackage{currfile}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\chead{\currfilename}
\ihead{\pagemark}
\ofoot*{}
\cfoot*{}

% \AddtoDoHook appends persistent code to the hook named name.
% \@gobble: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85796/why-does-gobble-take-one-argument
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,pagestyle=scrheadings]{section}% <- changed
\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=false}\@gobble}
  \renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \color{white}
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
          }%
        }%
      ]%
    }{%
      \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Second example:

```latex
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662860/komascript-section-header-over-two-column-text-layout
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn, chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[headsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- sets page style scrheadings automatically
\usepackage{currfile}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\chead{\currfilename}
\ihead{\pagemark}
\ofoot*{}
\cfoot*{}

% \AddtoDoHook appends persistent code to the hook named name.
% \@gobble: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85796/why-does-gobble-take-one-argument
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{section}
\renewcommand*{\sectionpagestyle}{scrheadings}% <- added
\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=false}\@gobble}
  \renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \color{white}
        \colorbox{black}{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{%
            \raggedsection
            \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
          }%
        }%
      ]%
    }{%
      \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Instead of

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{section}
```

use the modification

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,pagestyle=scrheadings]{section}
```

as it was suggested in comment.